# K-modes python installation using Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install K-modes package in Anaconda. 
I cannot find it in Anaconda anywhere.
How do I download and get it to work through an Anaconda distribution?

Answer (score 4):

I am on Mac and have just managed to install kmodes using pip and open in jupyter notebooks in Anaconda. If you are on Windows this might work differently, but you can try it.

First of all I opened the general terminal and I entered

`conda info --envs`

This shows you what virtual envs have been created in anaconda. It should show you one that says `base/` at the start. Simply write `source activate` and then copy and past the base pathway, and press enter. This will open your anaconda environment.

Then you can do `pip install kmodes` and enter, and this will install kmodes into your anaconda environment.

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Tried on Windows. It works! Use only 'activate' for Windows. Also after installation, you will not see in the Conda Installed Packages list. But it will work in your Python script